# a tags dont work when inside element with another href attribute

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have come across a problem with nesting two anchor tags in HTML. Nesting within anchor tags is not allowed, so I tried to workaround it by changing my first `a` attribute to `div`. Funcionality did not change, the link is highlighted and has correct link, however after clicking on the text first href triggers. Is there any way to workaround this kind of problem?

```
<div href="#collapse'.$x.'" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#affix_sidebar">
    <a href="index.php">'.$cat_name.'</a>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus floating_glyphicon"></span>
</div>
```

What a first `href` does, is that it triggers a accordion like submenu (shown in image). I tried to change the first href attribute not to be in a anchor tag, but I failed. Second anchor tag (the text) should be link for another page. Attaching picture for better explanation.
[image: For better explanation]

EDIT://
I have though about linking the first href action to the glyphicon only, leaving a attribute only for the text. My attempts are failing so far, but if anybody would know how to help in this direction I would be thankful.

Comment: Did you try changing the `href` attribute in the parent to `data-href` or some other `data-*` attribute?

Comment: I did. It does not make any difference.

Comment: I don’t think what you are trying to do is possible without JS – at least not _that_ way. I would consider putting a real `a` element in there to open the sub menu (this is what this seems to be, so you should mark it up as a nested `ul`/`li` list construct) – but not nested inside the other link, but simply before it. To get it positioned to achieve what you want should be possible quite easily, maybe even overlapping the second link, so that the first click anywhere on the whole line would open the sub menu.

Comment: The collapse menu is probably blocking your anchor event, you will need to find out if your script allows you to bypass this OR move the toggle to the symbols only.

Comment: It seems like you are right David. The menu simply registers click as the action for menu not the link. I simply could not find any solution so i have to workaround this problem completely without implementing my original intension.

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](http://www.wisephoenix.org/examples/css3/horizonTab.htm)If you are trying to create drop-down menus, with clickable links, look at the source-code for:

```
[Dropdownmenus][1]
```